# select SQL xml datatype to a dto

Tags: c#, xml

I have a `XML` column in the table. My domain model has this

```
[Column(TypeName = "xml")]
public string XmlContent { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public XElement XmlElement
{
    get { return XElement.Parse(XmlContent ); }
    set => XmlContent = value.ToString();
}
```

I have  a variable defined as `XElement` in my DTO, too.

```
public XElement XMLContent { get; set; }
```

I am using

```
var query = from a in _dbContext.table1
            where accountnumber = '123'
            orderby duedate descending
            select new myDto
                       {
                            Id = a.id,
                            accountNumber = a.accountnumber,                                
                            XMLContent = a.XmlElement
                       };

var items = await query.ToListAsync();
```

I am getting an error:

> Method not found: 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement table1.get_XmlElement()'.

Comment: Might be because linq does not know anything about XmlElement property - it's not mapped. You should use this property when you have retrieved results and not in query.

Comment: If I map the string property (in my case XmlContent  from table to a string property in dto , still getting the same error.  I don't want to load so many columns from database. Thats why I am mapping the columns I need to a dto.